How to override adminhtml js file in custom module?
I need to override below file in my custom module Ayakil_CatalogPermissionsExtended

vendor/magento/module-catalog-permissions/view/adminhtml/web/category_edit.js

The custom module was created and placed the category_edit.js(/app/code/Ayakil/CatalogPermissionsExtended/view/adminhtml/web/js/category_edit.js)
Content of requirejs-config.js is below
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_CatalogPermissions/js/category_edit': {
            'Ayakil_CatalogPermissionsExtended/js/category_edit': true
        }
    }
}
};

but unfortunately after static content deploy, in the admin section core vendor modules js file is picking up not the override one.
Any clue where i missed this overriding, it will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

To add a dependency in your custom module that builds on an existing module, update the module.xml file located in your custom module’s directory (app/code/Ayakil/CatalogPermissionsExtended/etc). Use the following format as an example:
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ayakil_CatalogPermissionsExtended">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogPermissions"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

Clean out the ./var/view_proprocessed/* directory to ensure that all old temporary files are removed. Re-run static content deployment.

Thanks for the answer, i have already added this
